# Use an extension method in a Viewbag

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, datetime, viewbag

I have the following extension method for DateTime type

```
public static class DateTimeHelper
{
    public static DateTime ToCST(this DateTime dt)
    {
        TimeZoneInfo cstZone = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Central Standard Time");
        DateTime cstTime = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(dt, cstZone);

        return cstTime;
    }
}
```

this works fine in the controller with DateTime objects, but in the view I want to use this in a ViewBag, just like this:

```
@ViewBag.PrioritySummary.UpdateDttm.ToCST();
```

I get the following error:

```
'System.DateTime' does not contain a definition for 'ToCST' 
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException: 'System.DateTime' does not contain a definition for 'ToCST'

Source Error: 

Line 8:      DateTime cstTime = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(ViewBag.PrioritySummary.UpdateDttm, cstZone);
Line 9:  }
Line 10: @ViewBag.PrioritySummary.UpdateDttm.ToCST();
```

How could I cast a ViewBag to DateTime, in order to apply the extension method, in the same line?

I tried:

```
@(DateTime)ViewBag.PrioritySummary.UpdateDttm.ToCST();
```

But this didn't work.

Comment: Did you add a @using statement to include the namespace where the `.ToCST()` method is?

Comment: @JLRishe Yep, I can use it in a block of razor for example. but I want to do it in-line

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should wrap your expression in parentheses:

```
@(((DateTime)ViewBag.PrioritySummary.UpdateDttm).ToCST());
```

and to add the corresponding `using` statement at the beginning of your view.

```
@using ...DateTimeHelper;
```

Comment: Hi thanks,  the '@' cast a razor line and when it complied it only interpret this: **@((DateTime)ViewBag.PrioritySummary.UpdateDttm)**.ToCST(); as a razor code. So the output is something like: 10/01/2016 2:51:10 PM.ToCST();

Comment: I think one more set of parentheses is needed: 
`@(((DateTime)ViewBag.PrioritySummary.UpdateDttm).ToCST())`

Comment: @MiguelRodrigoAlbarracin The issue with the parantheses has been solved, please see my update. However, I think that you will find another obstacle, please have a look here  https://dotnetfiddle.net/hEYm9V.

Answer (score 2):

The root cause of the error is that you cannot use extension methods on dynamic expressions, since they are bound at compile-time.  Since `ViewBag` is dynamic, the entire expression is bound at run-time.  When you cast to `DateTime`, the compiler can then bind to the static method.

Another option without the cast is to call the static method directly:

```
@DateTimeHelper.ToCST(ViewBag.PrioritySummary.UpdateDttm);
```

Neither case is completely type-save since you're using `dynamic`.  You'll either get an invalid cast exception or a runtime binding exception.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
@((DateTime)(ViewBag.PrioritySummary)).UpdateDttm.ToCST();
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi all thanks for your answers,
after I try your options I realized that is a '()' problem, 
the following line works fine for me.

```
@(((DateTime)(ViewBag.PrioritySummary).UpdateDttm).ToCST());
```

Thanks.